# Typing Custom Directives

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-directives

I would like to ask a question about Vue's custom directives. As a fan of Typescript, I want to use this feature with type support, yet I could not find any solutions neither on the web nor on the chat.

```html
<button v-clickOutside="myFunc"> Click Outside </button>
```

When I write my code like this, and add clickOutside directive to Vue, it works without any problem. Yet the **clickOutside** has no type support, no auto-complete support and it is recognized as **any**.

To define, I followed the documentation of Vue.

```
app.directive('clickOutside', (el, binding) => {
  // My code is here.
})
```

Answer (score 9):

This is possible using the `Directive<T,V>` type even though its poorly documented.

```
import { Directive } from 'vue'
```

The type takes two type arguments, one for the element type `T` and one for the binding value `V`. Use it like this:

```
app.directive('clickOutside', <Directive<HTMLElement,string>>{
  mounted (el, { value }) {
    // el:  HTMLElement
    // value: string
  }
})
```

Comment: Where did you find what these generic types represent. I can't find them anywhere on the vue docs site.

Comment: In the vue package source code. But it doesn’t really have any effect when using directives.

Comment: This isn't a correct answer. That types the directive within the defintion, but the question is referring to strong typing in the template.

Answer (score 4):

Typing custom global directives is currently not yet supported, but there's an open [Pull Request](https://github.com/vuejs/core/pull/3399) to add support for it.